# How to create a div element on another page when the form data is submitted using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'calibri regular';
    src: url('calibri-font/calibri-regular/calibri regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
body
{
    font-family: 'calibri regular' !important;
}


.top-head h2
{
    padding:0px;
}
input
{
    outline:none;
    border:none;
    margin-left:20px;
}
input[type="text"] {
    background: #EEEEEE 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;

}

.category-img {
/*    margin-top:50%;*/
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}

textarea {
    /* background: #EEEEEE 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box; */
    background: #EEEEEE 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 3.6vh;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 1.6vh;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 1.9vh;
    top: 0px;
    position: relative;
    /*  height: 5.3vh;*/
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 45.5vh;
    height: 20.5vh;
    outline: none;
    /* background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box; */
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 2.1vh;
    padding: 5px;
    opacity: 1;
}
form {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 58.2vh;
    height: 66vh;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px #00000029;
    opacity: 1;
}
.main-category {
    padding: 3.7vh 0px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.category-img {
    width: 64.1vh;
    height: 64.1vh;
    background: transparent url('img/3793120.png') 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    opacity: 1;
}
.column-half {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 5.3vh;
}

/*button[type="submit"] {
    margin-top: -25px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    background: transparent linear-gradient(106deg, #EB6B81 0%, #AB2CD8 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 34px;
    width: 20.9vh;
    height: 5.2vh;
    opacity: 1;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px 0px #8B8888;
    font-size: 1.9vh;
}
*/
/*button, html [type="button"], [type="reset"], [type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}

[type=button], [type=reset], [type=submit], button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}
*/
#myForm button {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 2.1vh;
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    outline: #912DAE;
    width: 20.9vh;
    height: 5.2vh;
    background: transparent linear-gradient(106deg, #EB6B81 0%, #AB2CD8 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border-radius: 34px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.8vh;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
}

label {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 6.1vh;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 1.9vh;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #4B4B4B;
    font-weight: 400;
}
h2 {
    text-align: left;
    font: Bold 3.2vh Calibri;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    color: #535353;
    opacity: 1;
    padding:3.2vh 2.1vh;
}
.form
{
    padding:10.6vh 0px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    position: relative;
    width: 2.5vh;
    margin-left: 4vh;
   
    top: 0px;
}
.activelabel {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 4.8vh;
    left: 3.8vh;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.box
{
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
                    <form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form">
                            <label for="cname">Category Name</label>
                            <input type="text" id="cname" name="categoryname" required>
                            <br>
                            <label for="desc">Description</label>
                            <textarea type="text" id="desc" name="description" required></textarea>
                            <label class="checkbox-inline" style="height: 0px; display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 0px">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="cbox" value="" />
                                <p class="activelabel">Active</p>
                            </label>
                            <label for="favcolor">Select your favorite color:</label>
                            <input type="color" id="favcolor" name="favcolor" value="#ff0000">

                            <button type="submit" onClick="testJS()">Add Category</button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="success_message"><p></p></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

> When the form filled and clicked on submit button, the div will create not in the same page, The DIv should create in different page or another page and the data filled in the form will be displayed inside the DiV created as well as the color choosen at the time of form fill, the div background color should be in same as color selected.

Comment: What server-side language are you using to process the submitted form data and generate the HTML on the other page? You can't achieve your requirement without server code

Comment: I am using javascript

Comment: Javascript is not a server-side language.

Comment: @FluffyKitten well it can be, if you have a nodeJS server. But I agree, that wasn't the implication here.

Comment: @Prince do you mean JavaScript running on nodeJS on your **server**? Other common examples of server side languages would be PHP, Java, ASP.NET, or python. JavaScript which is part of your web page is client-side script. That's not what I'm talking about. Do you understand how web applications are structured?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET